# Doctrine Mapping 2 levels of inheritance

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, mapping

I defined a mapping for

```
/**
 * Identite entity
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="identite")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"identite" = "Identite","candidat" = "Candidat","consultant"="Consultant","staff"="Staff" })
 */
class Identite extends ObjetEtat{


    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id; 
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nomidentite", type="string", length=200, nullable=true)
     */
    private $nomidentite;}
```

and I have the mapping of the super Class:

```
/**
 * Identite entity
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="objetetat")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discrimin", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"objetetat" = "ObjetEtat","identite" = "Sigmatis\SigBundle\Entity\Identites\Identite" })
 */

class ObjetEtat {
    //put your code here

        /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id; }
```

And this is the third level of my hierarchy :

```
/**
 * Candidat entity
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="candidat")

 */

class Candidat extends Identite {
}
```

After updating my schema : I don't find the field "discr " of my table Identite . Do I miss something ??

Comment: Do you have "discrimin" column in your "objetetat" table ?

Comment: Yes the  column "discrimin" exists there , and when I insert an object (Candidat or  Staff) , the value of the discrimin takes : Candidat  or staff. But what I need is that : discrimin will take the value "identite" and in the table Identite, I want to have a column named discr where I will have : candidat,or staff

Comment: Do you have any idea about that please ??

Answer (score 1):

You should put the `@ORM\DiscriminatorColumn` and `@ORM\DiscriminatorMap` annotations on the superclass, not the child one

Comment: Thnx for the reply , but I need it in the child too, because the child has its subclasses ( Candidat, consultant,staff .....)